# Create index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, document

I want to create Index in mongodb , but with the classic method

> db.OPC_PLANT_DATA.createIndex( { "ITEM_ID" : 1.0,"ITEM_TIMESTAMP" : -1.0 } )

the db get stucked and it takes lot of time , so if I want to do it in Production it will impcat all the work !!

Someone knows how to do it without having any impact on documents insertion ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo Db allowed creation of indices in background. You had to specify `background:true` option while creating an index.

This was deprecated in version 4.2 of mongo though because they've optimized the index creation process.

Read the [relevant documentation chapter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#ensureindex-options)

Comment: can you please give me the exactly place os syntaxe where to specify background:true in the query

Comment: `db.collection.createIndex(<keys_to_create_index>, {'background' : true})` I guess (don't have a working mongo instance to check). Here is a documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/